# IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3 maven build doesn't work

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I'm wrtting a multimodule project with intelliJ IDEA

my parent pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>imp.macchineCiemme</groupId>
    <artifactId>macchineCiemme</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <modules>
        <module>dummy</module>
        <module>common</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        ...
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

My children pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>macchineCiemme</artifactId>
        <groupId>imp.macchineCiemme</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>common</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

</project>  



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>macchineCiemme</artifactId>
        <groupId>imp.macchineCiemme</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>dummy</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>imp.macchineCiemme</groupId>
            <artifactId>common</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

if I try to compile / build the project

[image]

I get this error message

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2\bin\java.exe" -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=D:\development\JetBrains\macchineCiemme -Xms2048M -Xmx2048M "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.5.3\lib\springloaded-1.2.8.RELEASE.jar" -noverify "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" "-Dmaven.ext.class.path=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven-event-listener.jar" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=65329:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds.license" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2020.3.2 clean
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.
mar 08, 2021 7:26:03 PM org.springsource.loaded.agent.SpringLoadedPreProcessor preProcess
SEVERE: Unexpected problem transforming call sites
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at sl.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sl.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springsource.loaded.MethodInvokerRewriter.rewrite(MethodInvokerRewriter.java:345)
    at org.springsource.loaded.MethodInvokerRewriter.rewrite(MethodInvokerRewriter.java:99)
    at org.springsource.loaded.TypeRegistry.methodCallRewriteUseCacheIfAvailable(TypeRegistry.java:1002)
    at org.springsource.loaded.agent.SpringLoadedPreProcessor.preProcess(SpringLoadedPreProcessor.java:361)
    at org.springsource.loaded.agent.ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.transform(ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.java:107)
    at java.instrument/java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer.transform(ClassFileTransformer.java:246)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:563)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass2(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1108)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:183)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:784)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassInModuleOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:705)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:586)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:546)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.loadProvider(ServiceLoader.java:854)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ModuleServicesLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1078)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1301)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1386)
    at java.base/sun.util.cldr.CLDRLocaleProviderAdapter$1.run(CLDRLocaleProviderAdapter.java:89)
    at java.base/sun.util.cldr.CLDRLocaleProviderAdapter$1.run(CLDRLocaleProviderAdapter.java:86)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:554)
    at java.base/sun.util.cldr.CLDRLocaleProviderAdapter.<init>(CLDRLocaleProviderAdapter.java:86)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at java.base/sun.util.locale.provider.LocaleProviderAdapter.forType(LocaleProviderAdapter.java:188)
    at java.base/sun.util.locale.provider.LocaleProviderAdapter.findAdapter(LocaleProviderAdapter.java:287)
    at java.base/sun.util.locale.provider.LocaleProviderAdapter.getAdapter(LocaleProviderAdapter.java:258)
    at java.base/java.util.Calendar.createCalendar(Calendar.java:1693)
    at java.base/java.util.Calendar.getInstance(Calendar.java:1661)
    at java.base/java.text.SimpleDateFormat.initializeCalendar(SimpleDateFormat.java:677)
    at java.base/java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:621)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusDateTypeConverter.<clinit>(PlexusDateTypeConverter.java:37)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer$DefaultsModule.<init>(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:851)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.<init>(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:147)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.container(MavenCli.java:636)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:282)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1427)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)

---------------------------------------------------
constituent[0]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202020.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/conf/logging/
constituent[1]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202020.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/cdi-api-1.0.jar
constituent[2]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202020.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/commons-cli-1.4.jar
constituent[3]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202020.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/commons-io-2.5.jar
constituent[4]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202020.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar
constituent[5]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202020.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/guava-25.1-android.jar
constituent[6]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202020.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/guice-4.2.1-no_aop.jar
constituent[7]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202020.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/jansi-1.17.1.jar
constituent[8]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202020.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/javax.inject-1.jar
constituent[9]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202020.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.29.jar
constituent[10]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202020.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/jsoup-1.12.1.jar
constituent[11]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202020.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/jsr250-api-1.0.jar
constituent[12]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202020.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-artifact-3.6.3.jar
constituent[13]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202020.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-builder-support-3.6.3.jar
constituent[14]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202020.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-compat-3.6.3.jar
constituent[15]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202020.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-core-3.6.3.jar
constituent[16]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202020.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-embedder-3.6.3.jar
constituent[17]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202020.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-model-3.6.3.jar
constituent[18]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202020.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-model-builder-3.6.3.jar
constituent[19]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202020.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-plugin-api-3.6.3.jar
constituent[20]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202020.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-repository-metadata-3.6.3.jar
constituent[21]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202020.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-resolver-api-1.4.1.jar
constituent[22]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202020.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-resolver-connector-basic-1.4.1.jar
constituent[23]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202020.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-resolver-impl-1.4.1.jar
constituent[24]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202020.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-resolver-provider-3.6.3.jar
constituent[25]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202020.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-resolver-spi-1.4.1.jar
constituent[26]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202020.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-resolver-transport-wagon-1.4.1.jar
constituent[27]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202020.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-resolver-util-1.4.1.jar
constituent[28]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202020.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-settings-3.6.3.jar
constituent[29]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202020.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-settings-builder-3.6.3.jar
constituent[30]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202020.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-shared-utils-3.2.1.jar
constituent[31]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202020.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-slf4j-provider-3.6.3.jar
constituent[32]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202020.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.3.4.jar
constituent[33]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202020.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/org.eclipse.sisu.plexus-0.3.4.jar
constituent[34]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202020.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/plexus-cipher-1.7.jar
constituent[35]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202020.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/plexus-component-annotations-2.1.0.jar
constituent[36]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202020.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/plexus-interpolation-1.25.jar
constituent[37]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202020.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.4.jar
constituent[38]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202020.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/plexus-utils-3.2.1.jar
constituent[39]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202020.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.29.jar
constituent[40]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202020.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/wagon-file-3.3.4.jar
constituent[41]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202020.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/wagon-http-3.3.4-shaded.jar
constituent[42]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202020.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/wagon-provider-api-3.3.4.jar
---------------------------------------------------
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: Locale provider adapter "CLDR"cannot be instantiated.
    at java.base/sun.util.locale.provider.LocaleProviderAdapter.forType(LocaleProviderAdapter.java:199)
    at java.base/sun.util.locale.provider.LocaleProviderAdapter.findAdapter(LocaleProviderAdapter.java:287)
    at java.base/sun.util.locale.provider.LocaleProviderAdapter.getAdapter(LocaleProviderAdapter.java:258)
    at java.base/java.util.Calendar.createCalendar(Calendar.java:1693)
    at java.base/java.util.Calendar.getInstance(Calendar.java:1661)
    at java.base/java.text.SimpleDateFormat.initializeCalendar(SimpleDateFormat.java:677)
    at java.base/java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:621)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusDateTypeConverter.<clinit>(PlexusDateTypeConverter.java:37)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer$DefaultsModule.<init>(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:851)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.<init>(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:147)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.container(MavenCli.java:636)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:282)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1427)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at java.base/sun.util.locale.provider.LocaleProviderAdapter.forType(LocaleProviderAdapter.java:188)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: sun.util.locale.provider.LocaleDataMetaInfo: Unable to load sun.util.resources.cldr.provider.CLDRLocaleDataMetaInfo
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:584)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.loadProvider(ServiceLoader.java:856)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ModuleServicesLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1078)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1301)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1386)
    at java.base/sun.util.cldr.CLDRLocaleProviderAdapter$1.run(CLDRLocaleProviderAdapter.java:89)
    at java.base/sun.util.cldr.CLDRLocaleProviderAdapter$1.run(CLDRLocaleProviderAdapter.java:86)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:554)
    at java.base/sun.util.cldr.CLDRLocaleProviderAdapter.<init>(CLDRLocaleProviderAdapter.java:86)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader 'platform' attempted duplicate class definition for sun.util.resources.cldr.provider.CLDRLocaleDataMetaInfo. (sun.util.resources.cldr.provider.CLDRLocaleDataMetaInfo is in module jdk.localedata of loader 'platform')
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass2(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1108)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:183)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:784)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassInModuleOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:705)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:586)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:546)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.loadProvider(ServiceLoader.java:854)
    ... 35 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

My IntelliJ configuration for maven is
[image]

The command line IntelliJ generates for me is

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2\bin\java.exe" -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=D:\development\JetBrains\demo -Xms2048M -Xmx2048M "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.5.3\lib\springloaded-1.2.8.RELEASE.jar" -noverify "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" "-Dmaven.ext.class.path=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven-event-listener.jar" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=56236:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds.license" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2020.3.2 -DskipTests=true install

That generate the same error if run in powershell

Is it something in my configuration that is broken? Is this the correct way to generate a multilevel project in intelliJ?

Comment: It looks like you are using the wrong Maven version: `apache-maven-3.5.3\`...Remove your run configurations with `-Xverify:none`...also check your project on plain command line...

Comment: Can you provide a sample project to reproduce? Some your configuration loads the `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.5.3\lib\springloaded-1.2.8.RELEASE.jar` javaagent jar. Do you have it configured soewhere? Do you use Maven wrapper in project?

Comment: How can a provvide a sample project? I a new IntelliJ User. It appends also when I create  a basic maven project for example a simple Spring project. 
I can compile it with Gradle, or generate the full package as an intelliJ Artifact but if a ask IntelliJ to run Maven package, it comes up with the complicated command line I added in my post. 
The same command line generate the same error if run by powershell but both the standard maven syntax (mvn instal) and eclpse work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case it was environment variable

```
MAVEN_OPTS
```

that contained a dirty value. I reset the value to

```
MAVEN_OPTS = -Xms2048M -Xmx2048M -noverify
```

reboot my computer and worked